# Why can't I delete rows in excel files, using openpyxl

Tags: python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I'm doing data science projects, and I'm working with an Excel file that contains the data on temperatures. Long story short, I'm concerned with columns D and E, which they may contain values like '***' or '#'. When I encounter these cells, I want to delete the entire row that contains the cell.

Below shows my code:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel = load_workbook('CLMMAXT_TMS_.xlsx').active
for i in reversed(range(2, 10000)):
    value_sharp = excel[f'E{i}'].value
    value_asterisk = excel[f'D{i}'].value
    if value_sharp == '#' or value_asterisk == '***':
        excel.delete_rows(i, amount=1)
        print(f'{i}: {value_asterisk}, {value_sharp}')
```

I have absolutely no idea why this code does not work. It just didn't delete even ONE row. I have read similar questions and tried their solutions such as the `reversed()` method, but they didn't work either. Can anyone tell me where I made the mistake and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not saving your changes. You have to save the workbook, have separate variables for `workbook` and `active_sheet`. `workbook = load_workbook('<path_to_file')` and `excel = workbook.active`. After the changes try and save the workbook by `workbook.save(<path_to_file>)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may sound trivial but you need to [`save`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.workbook.workbook.html?highlight=save#openpyxl.workbook.workbook.Workbook.save) the changes (*and your code will work 100% fine*).

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

excel = load_workbook('file.xlsx')
sheet = excel.active

for i in reversed(range(2, 10000)):
    value_sharp = sheet[f'E{i}'].value
    value_asterisk = sheet[f'D{i}'].value
    if value_sharp == '#' or value_asterisk == '***':
        sheet.delete_rows(i, amount=1)
        # print(f'{i}: {value_asterisk}, {value_sharp}')
        
excel.save('output.xlsx')
```

Output :

[image]